# android - attempting transparent background of a layout overlay

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview

I'm trying to make a popup that will appear over a listview, with a transparent background so you can still see the listview behind it.

Here is the xml of the popup:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/background"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/popup_bg"
        android:padding="20dip" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <!-- Left column -->

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/foodName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/calories"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/foodName"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fat"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/calories"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/protein"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/fat"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/carbohydrates"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/protein"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
            <!-- Bottom -->

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sodium"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/carbohydrates"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnAddFood"
                android:layout_width="200dip"
                android:layout_height="50dip"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/sodium"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/popup_buttons"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Add this food" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the activity that calls it (with some unnecessary lines deleted):

```
public class FoodPopupActivity extends Activity{
     String foodName;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        try{
        // receive food
         Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
         final Food food = (Food) extras.get("food");
         String foodName = food.getName();


        // set view
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_food_popup);

        View background = findViewById(R.id.background);
        // background.setBackgroundColor(00000000);


        background.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1){
                finish();
                return false;
            }
        });


        addFood.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // pass an intent with user location and where they need to go
                // then start the intent
                MainActivity.myMeal.addFood(food);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),food.getName()+" added to your menu for today.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        });



        }catch(Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error displaying food data, Try again, "+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),foodName+" "+String.valueOf(foodCalories), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }

}
```

I believe I've tried loading this over a relative layout, a linear layout and a listview without success so far. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Change

`android:background="#00000000"`

to

`android:background="@android:color/transparent"`

plus you will need to remove `android:background="@drawable/popup_bg"` from your `FrameLayout`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I tried both of those. Changing the background to transparent doesn't do anything. Deleting the 'popup_bg' from FrameLayout just removes my custom border I have for the frame.

Comment: [Here's the listview I want to be able to see in the background](http://i.imgur.com/Ago2INF.png)

[And here's the popup overlay](http://i.imgur.com/YKZvPWn.png)

Comment: Is it appearing this way even after you apply `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the background image as a transparent image. You can easily create one and save it as a png file.

```
android:background="@drawable/transparent_image"
```

This does the trick for me..

Answer (score 0):

Use this woking for me for transparent background....

```
  framelayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set black as `background` color and to make it transparent, try using `alpha` attribute:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/black_layer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:alpha="0.75" />
```